# Collision in Cocos2d

Tags: collision-detection, cocos2d-x

I am beginner in Game Development in Cocos2d, and I have been through a tutorial of raywenderlich,[http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial,) 
The problem is that i want to detect a collision between the monster with the player object like the following code

```
-(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
    [self addMonster];
    for (CCSprite *monster in _monsters) {

            CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(
                                           monster.position.x - (monster.contentSize.width/2),
                                           monster.position.y - (monster.contentSize.height/2),
                                           monster.contentSize.width,
                                           monster.contentSize.height);
            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(targetRect, player.boundingBox)) {
                NSLog(@"Intersect Right!");
            }

    }
} 

-(id) init
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"background-music-aac.caf"];
    _monsters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _projectiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if ((self = [super initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)])) {
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"player.png"];
        [player setColor:ccRED];
        player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:player];
    }
    [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1.0];
    [self schedule:@selector(update:)];
    [self setTouchEnabled:YES];
    return self;
}

- (void) addMonster {
    CCSprite * monster = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"monster.png"];

    // Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    int minY = monster.contentSize.height / 2;
    int maxY = winSize.height - monster.contentSize.height/2;
    int rangeY = maxY - minY;
    int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

    // Create the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
    // and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above

    monster.position = ccp(winSize.width + monster.contentSize.width/2, actualY);
    [self addChild:monster];

    // Determine speed of the monster
    int minDuration = 2.0;
    int maxDuration = 4.0;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    // Create the actions
    CCMoveTo * actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                                position:ccp(-monster.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
    CCCallBlockN * actionMoveDone = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
//        CCScene *gameOver = [GameOverLayer sceneWithWon:NO];
//        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOver];
        [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }];
    [monster runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
    monster.tag = 1;
    [_monsters addObject:monster];
}
```

But i can't get the accurate hit between those 2 object and even sometimes those 2 object hit each other directly but it's seem log wasn't run.

Comment: Why you are not using the monster's bounding box for the collision ?

Comment: it doesn't work for bounding box. i try many other think that posted on stackover flow but still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be helpful to see player and monster creation code. But I can assume that they have different parents. In this case they can have not intersected rects even if visually they are at the same position. Node's position is relatieve to it's parent, not the whole scene. If you want to use world coordinates, use `convertToWorldSpace:` method.

EDIT:
Solved in comments.

"Your collision detection is in the method that is called only once a second. Try to move it to your update: method instead."

Comment: This how i created player sprite  `- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"player.png"];
        player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:player];
    }
    return self;
}`   and here is how i create monster `CCSprite * monster = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"monster.png"];`   and some other line of code to make it appear randomly on the screen. Basically, i just followed the full tutorial of raywenderlich of the link above.

Comment: you should edit your question rather then post code in comments. it is quite hard to be read. post initialization of your `player` variable, that you use in the `gameLogic:` method

Comment: Still don't see your `player` variable initialization. In the `init` method you are using local variable to create sprite. What variable do you use in the `gameLogic:` method? Also there is no code to add your monster sprite to `_monsters` container, so in this case your `for` cycle will be just skipped as `_monsters` is empty.

Comment: I'v updated the post, i have declared player as the global variable. and add the monster to _monster array.

Comment: your collision detection is in the method that is called only once a second. try to move it to your `update:` method instead.

Comment: You are welcome. You can mark answer as correct to help others to find it in future

Comment: Anyway, is there any fast and easy way to learn cocos2d @Morion? Would you mind give me some recommendation.

Comment: Cocos2d is written rather well. You can get answers to many of your questions just reading it's code and failed assertion messages in console. And you can get a lot of info here, on stackoverflow. There are a lot of questions with good answers about such things as anchor points, transformations, batching, using atlases, etc.

Comment: i got it. i'm gonna read more on Cocos2d n Stackoverflow :D !